# MySQL -- Select year from a format like "2010-07-30 22:58:59"

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all records from a MySQL data base that are older than the year 2013.  I've tried this...

`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,date_sent) < 2013`

but it didn't work.  The `DATEPART` idea came from here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: W3fools is an utterly useless resource, and `datepart()` does not exist in MySQL. Use the **REAL** docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE YEAR(date_sent) < 2013
```

Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `date_sent` is a date field, you can use [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE YEAR(date_sent) < 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look over the [actual documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE added_date < '2013-01-01'
```